# How to update table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, redraw, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` with one big cell and many small cells. When I receive content from server I update my `UITableView` with function `- (BOOL)performFetch:(NSError **)error` (`NSFetchedResultsController`). I noticed that my big cell has dublicate after update and the second cell doesn't reload. When I scroll down and scroll to top table looks good.
How can I solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: try [tableView reloadData];

Comment: @MerleaDan, If I update table with [tableView reloadData]; I haven't row animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"performFetch" updates the datasource but the tableview itself is not updated.

For updating the tableview use either

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

or

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

You can pick the animation you like best, for example UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle or just UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic

For performance reasons update only as much as necessary.