# How to update tableview cell without reload data ?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a tableview cell.
In this cell there is a view that plays video, and star rating under this 
video view.

I want want user to not rate until watch video's %50 part.
if user watched video's %50 part, user can rate this video.

In my model class I set a timer. When user click a video play timer starting to play and if timer == video duration/2 user can rate. otherwise

user show alert message..

**What I did :**  When timer == video duration/2 
i reload the tableview / or just reload the row

but video is stopped.

How can I do this ? Any advice or sample code please ?

**Here is my play button custom delegate func**

```
if(vlist[index.row].timerIndex >= 10){
                        print("====================!!!!!!!!!!^^^^^^^^^^^^^^======RATABLEEEEEEEEEEE")
                        vlist[index.row].isRatable = true
                        self.rateUserTableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
                        MediaManager.sharedInstance.player?.embeddedContentView = cell.videoPlayerView
                        vlist[index.row].timer?.invalidate()
                    }
```

**and here is my tableview ccellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let vlist = videoList ,!vlist.isEmpty else {let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.textLabel?.text = "nodataavaiable".localized()
            return cell
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RateUserCell", for: indexPath) as! RateUserCell
        //---
        let playing = vlist[indexPath.row].isPlaying
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        cell.playButton.isHidden = playing
        cell.titleView.isHidden = playing
        //---
        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named:"thumb1")
        }
        else {
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named:"thumb2")
        }
        cell.titleLabel.text = vlist[indexPath.row].shortDesc
        cell.userName.text = vlist[indexPath.row].person
        cell.userCount.text = String(vlist[indexPath.row].voteCount!)
        cell.voteCount.text = String(vlist[indexPath.row].sumScore!)
        cell.cosmos.rating = Double(vlist[indexPath.row].userVote!)



        if(self.statusId == 3 ){
            if(vlist[indexPath.row].userVote! > 0){
                cell.cosmos.didFinishTouchingCosmos =  { rating in
                    self.setVote(videoId: vlist[indexPath.row].videoId!, vote: Int(rating))
                }
            }
            else {

                if(vlist[indexPath.row].isRatable == true){
                    cell.cosmos.didTouchCosmos = { rating in
                        cell.cosmos.settings.updateOnTouch = true
                        cell.cosmos.rating = rating
                        self.setVote(videoId: vlist[indexPath.row].videoId!, vote: Int(rating))
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cell.cosmos.didTouchCosmos = { rating in
                        cell.cosmos.rating = Double(0.0)
                        self.showAlertMessage(vc: self, titleStr: "error".localized(), messageStr: "rateTimeMsj".localized(), img: "ntf-5", buttonColor: UIColor.red)
                        cell.cosmos.settings.updateOnTouch = false
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        else if(self.statusId == 4){
            cell.cosmos.isHidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated but why is `videoList` optional and why do you check for empty array every time `cellForRow` is called (which happens very often). This is unnecessarily expensive. A data source array is supposed to be non-optional and `cellForRow` won't be called at all if `numberOfRows` returns 0. And getting the same object 6 or 7 times from the array (`vlist[indexPath.row]`) is unnecessarily expensive, too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929510/how-to-update-table-view-cell

Comment: why do you need to reload the table or cell??

Comment: because after reading your question what i understand is you want the video to keep running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `tableView.cellForRow` to get the cell and configure it directly yourself only with the modified data:

```
// this should give you currently visible cell for indexPath
if let ratableCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RatableCell {
    // instead of telling tableView to reload this cell, just configure here
    // the changed data, e.g.:
    ratableCell.configureRate(10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code for reloading a single/Multiple rows on a specific indexpath.

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .top)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your cell with it's identifier and use awakFromnib(), worked for me

```
 if let receiverCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Receiver", for: indexe) as? ReceiverCell {

//    instead of telling tableView to reload this cell, just configure here
receiverCell.awakeFromNib()

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to do this.
EITHER You can reload particular cell then reloading table view.

**Using :-**

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
```

OR You can get the Instance of Particular cell and You can modify them as per your requirement.

**Using :-**

```
guard let particularCell = tableView.cellForRows(at: indexPath) as? CellName else {
return 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`tableView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)` this line will do nothing but it will refresh you data without `reloadData`.